# Python reading path wrong

Tags: python, path

So I have this piece of code that opens a JSON file. (Already imported JSON)

```
with open("Python\videoid.json", "r") as json_file:
```

The problem is that python is reading the `\v` part wrong and telling me that the file doesn't exist. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Change it to `/`, double it as `\\ `, or use a raw string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python ‘\’ is the escape key, do python thinks you are trying to use an escape character you can fix this with making is a raw string:

```
with open(r”Python\videoid.json", "r") as json_file:
# the r tells python to make it a raw string
```

Or you can add another backslash:

```
with open("Python\\videoid.json", "r") as json_file:
# tells python you want to actually do a backslash key
```

The comments on the lines explain it.